# Security concerns with DB backed Liquid Templates and Marshal.load

Tags: ruby, security, user-input, liquid, unmarshalling

I'm storing email templates in PostgreSQL so that users can edit outgoing emails. I'm using Liquid to prevent code execution on the server. In order to help speed up the process of fetching the email template from the db, parsing it, and then rendering it I'd like to Marshal the liquid template. Here is the code to do this:

```
# Saving template to the db
text = "template text from possibly dangerous user {{stuff}}"
template = Liquid::Template.parse(text)
email_template = EmailTemplate.new # the db class
email_template.source = Marshal.dump(template)
email_template.save

# time goes by and now we need that template
template = Marshal.load(email_template.source) # !! Is this dangerous? !!
```

I have read that `Marshal.load` can lead to remote code execution. I'm going to marshal the a Liquid::Template object but this does contain data supplied by scary users. Are there any security considerations I need to be aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoritically there *is* a security issue in your implementation.

From the [Ruby documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Marshal.html):

> By design, ::load can deserialize almost any class loaded into the
>   Ruby process. In many cases this can lead to remote code execution if
>   the Marshal data is loaded from an untrusted source.
>
> As a result, ::load is not suitable as a general purpose serialization
>   format and you should never unmarshal user supplied input or other
>   untrusted data.
>
> If you need to deserialize untrusted data, use JSON or another
>   serialization format that is only able to load simple, ‘primitive’
>   types such as String, Array, Hash, etc. Never allow user input to
>   specify arbitrary types to deserialize into.

Practically though, in your case any malicious input is taken care of by Liquid, so you should be just fine.

That said, I don't really see any reason for serializing/deserializing at all since your templates are just plain text. There is even a performance penalty when serializing/deserializing.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have another option for me to accomplish the above?

Comment: @bennick Sorry, missed my last line. Added it now.

Comment: Okay cool. I was just not sure if any remote code exception could "leak" though the Liquid::Template object during the Marshal.load process.

Comment: @bennick If you give malicious input to Liquid, its output is non-malicious so what you pass to `Marshal.load` is not malicious. However, I don't see the point of serialization/deserialization.

Comment: @bennick I've added a comment regarding your implementation generally.

Comment: I was going off of this old article that show a speed improvement over the Liquid parse. https://web.archive.org/web/20130221045519/http://cjohansen.no/en/rails/liquid_email_templates_in_rails

Comment: After running it I get user     system      total        real
deserialize:   1.440000   0.000000   1.440000 (  1.445489)
parse:   1.800000   0.010000   1.810000 (  1.810491)

Comment: Sorry I was not clear. I mean, why not save the parsed template into the db instead of saving it serialized?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that with Liquid::Template. I figured I'd need to serialize that object in order to save it to the DB.

Comment: You can somehow just get the string template (maybe call `#to_s`?) and just save this straight to the DB. However I don't find this a good idea and I don't think it's worth it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112960/discussion-between-bennick-and-agis).